# On click trigger radio button is not responding

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, wordpress

i am having an issue, currently i am using **cforms II** and displaying a form on Sponsership page, but my client requirment is to show some radio buttons, but when someone click on any one of these radio button then next input field should display.

[Sponsorship Application Link](http://www.contestsforhealth.com/sponsorship/)

[image]

please help me to resolve this..

thank you,

Comment: can you show what have you tried so far??

Comment: i saw your code..initially i guess your "Enter hoplink with..." textarea should be hidden..and when a user clicks yes button..then your textarea should be shown..am i correct??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

    jQuery("#radioButton").click(function() {
        if(jQuery(this).is(":checked") ) {
            jQuery("#showValue").show();
    } else {
      jQuery("#showValue").hide();
    }
    }); 

});
```

Answer (score 1):

The radio buttons have the same 'name', but different 'value's, right? Instead of a 'click' event, try the 'change' event. I've had issues like this in the past (usually browser specific), where switching to the 'change' event resolved the issue.

Comment: friend i am using cforms II, wordpress plugin. So if i need to change the codes, then i have to change the core plugin files. but i am asking for alternative way to resolve this issue,

Comment: no need to change in plugin files just go to header.php and add my code in head section just give the exact id name and radio button name

Comment: `jQuery(document).ready(function() {

    jQuery("#radioButton").click(function() {
        if(jQuery(this).is(":checked") ) {
            jQuery("#showValue").show();
    } else {
      jQuery("#showValue").hide();
    }
    }); 

});
`

Comment: if you wanted to hide `<li id="li--15" class="">` and show when click on 'cf_field_14-1`

Comment: then add these line `jQuery(document).ready(function() { 
jQuery("#li--15").hide();
 jQuery("#cf_field_14-1").click(function() { 
  if(jQuery(this).is(":checked") ) { 
   jQuery("#li--15").show(); 
   } else { 
   jQuery("#li--15").hide(); 
  } 
 });
});`

Answer (score 1):

//You are trying mr jassi9911 code please try this its working

$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#yesradioubuttonid").click(function(){

```
   $("#textareaid").css("display","block");
```

});

$("$noradiobuttonid").click(function(){

```
   $("#textareaid").css("display",'none');
```

}); 
});

Answer (score 1):

i have created a jsfiddle, initially you need to hide that textarea, and when someone clicks, it should show that textarea..have a look

http://jsfiddle.net/9kQkG/3/